# MySQL INSERT IGNORE in this case

Tags: mysql, sql

In this case, how can I use `insert ignore` to prevent duplicate rows being inserted?

It all on the userId and elmCol

So:

```
userId | elmCol
----------------
 1     | 1 //Allow
 1     | 2 //Allow
 1     | 3 //Allow
 1     | 1 //Not allowed if inserted again. I've put it in here just for example)
 2     | 1 //Allow
 2     | 2 //Allow
 2     | 3 //Allow
 2     | 1 //Not allowed if inserted again. I've put it in here just for example)
```

I'm using MySql and MyIsam type tables. Can I do something like this and use `insert ignore`?

I tried creating primary keys, but cannot use them on all columns.

Comment: Use On Duplicate Key Update instead.

Take a look at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: But I have nothing to update! If a duplicate row was inserted, simply don't insert it. That's all I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Norman from where you get this value..i mean how you inserting in this table one by one or whole as table

Comment: It comes from a php script. One row only.

Comment: @Norman: You're right, sorry I wasn't aware these are the only columns in your table. A composite primary key should solve your problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a composite primary key:
[How can I define a composite primary key in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110349/how-can-define-a-composite-primary-key-in-sql)

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable(
  userId NUMERIC,
  elmCol NUMERIC,
  PRIMARY KEY (userId , elmCol)
);
```

Once you got a composite primary key, you will not be able to insert duplicates.

By the way, **you should not use Unique Index** for this case because they can be nullable.
Check out this link, why not: 
[Primary key or Unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487314/primary-key-or-unique-index)

Comment: Amazing. I was trying the same thing, but using HeidiSQL and it would not allow me to add a secondary PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1):

Apply unique Index on both the column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE  INDEX unique_userId_elmCol    
    ON table1 (userId ,elmCol);
```

OR If you don't want to insert duplicate values in table and rather wants to keep that value in different table.

You can create trigger on table. like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER unique_key_ignore BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE c INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c FROM table1 WHERE userId = NEW.userId and elmCol = NEW.elmCol;
  IF (c > 0) THEN
    insert into table2 (userId ,elmCol) values ( NEW.userId , NEW.elmCol);
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```