# How to Redirect user to some other page if Duplicate Entry Error Occurs?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, duplicates

I am trying to redirect user to some other page when duplicate Entry Error Occurs. I am using 
`Codeigniter`

. I have written the following code, but it displays the error message `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'semester_id'`.

Kindly check the code and guide me.

Thanks

```
public function insert_sports_sports($student_id, $squash, $football, $cricket, $hockey, $swimming, $semester_id)
{
    $data= array (

            "squash"=> $squash,
            "football"=>$football,
            "cricket"=>$cricket,
            "hockey"=>$hockey,
            "swimming"=>$swimming,
            "studentId"=>$student_id,
            "semester_id" => $semester_id

    );  

    if ($this->db->insert("sports",$data))
    {
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
---
--
--
    if($this->loginmodel->insert_sports_sports($student_id, $squash, $football, $cricket,
                                             $hockey, $swimming, $semester_id))
    {
        redirect('mycontroller/index');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('success');
            }
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
    if ($this->db->insert("sports",$data))
    {
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            }
    }


catch (Exception $ex) {

        if($ex->message == "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'semester_id'")
        {
            redirect('success.php');    

            }       
}
}
```

***ERROR MESSAGE***

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '1' for key 'semester_id'

INSERT INTO `sports` (`squash`, `football`, `cricket`, `hockey`, `swimming`, `studentId`, `semester_id`) VALUES ('4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '42', '1')

Filename: F:\xampp\htdocs\student_management2\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: That essentially means that semester_id is a unique key, meaning that there's already an entry in the database where that column has a value of 1. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487314/primary-key-or-unique-index/2916464#2916464) page explains it all.

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to display this error message, i want to redirect user to some other page and display customized error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove try catch and try this

```
$orig_debug = $this->db->db_debug;
$this->db->db_debug = FALSE;

if ($this->db->insert("sports",$data))
 {
    $this->db->db_debug = $orig_debug;
    return true;
 }
else
 {
   $this->db->db_debug = $orig_debug;
    return false;
 }
```

it basically mutes the debug for your insert query.in case of error, no insertion takes place hence it will return false.

Answer (score 3):

If you want only to redirect on an error

```
try {
    $data= array (

            "squash"=> $squash,
            "football"=>$football,
            "cricket"=>$cricket,
            "hockey"=>$hockey,
            "swimming"=>$swimming,
            "studentId"=>$student_id,
            "semester_id" => $semester_id

    );  

    if ($this->db->insert("sports",$data))
    {
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            }
    }
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    if($ex->message == "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'semester_id'")
        redirect('yourpage.php');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply..I am still getting the same error message.. I have updated my question.. Kindly check it again.

Comment: My bad I have forgotten to access message property of an exception. Change $ex to $ex->message, if does not work just echo $ex->message in catch block than change the message to be compared

Comment: $ex->getMessage() or you can change if($ex->message == "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'semester_id'") to if($ex->getLine() == 330) redirect('page'); though it is not fully correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent it by setting rule for semester_id as follows

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('semester_id', 'input_name', 'trim|required|is_unique[TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME]');
```

Comment: +1 for utilizing the CI core though answer needs some tweaks (its not a form too) but appreciate the answer.