# Best type of index for unique column where queries will be faster if data is physically sorted

Tags: database, indexing

I want to create an index on a column such that the select statement require min time to retrieve the data. The column is unique and if data is physically sorted, query will be faster. Which index would you use?.

1. Clustered
2. Non-Clustered
3. Unique
4. Composite

Answer (score 0):

I think the clustered index is the right answer here.
It sorts the data physically to get better performance.

Wikipedia says:

> Clustered indices can greatly increase overall speed of retrieval, but usually only where the data is accessed sequentially in the same or reverse order of the clustered index, or when a range of items is selected.
>   Since the physical records are in this sort order on disk, the next row item in the sequence is immediately before or after the last one, and so fewer data block reads are required.

**Some SO questions that might help to understand the topic:**

[When should I use a composite index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823685/when-should-i-use-a-composite-index)

[Primary key or Unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487314/primary-key-or-unique-index)

[What do Clustered and Non clustered index actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean)